# Passing an Object to an $http POST in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having some trouble with passing a parameter to a POST using $http in AngularJS

My Object Parameter:

```
var myObject = { 
  ID: 1, 
  ARRAYOFSTUFF: [
    {1, "Test", 3, "TestA"},
    {2, "XXX", 9, "DDDD"},
    {5, "TUUU", 6, "TeUUUU"}
  ]
}
```

So I call post like this:

```
$http({ method: "POST", url: MYURL_URL, params: myObject, cache: false });
```

It gets to my endpoint but the `ARRAYOFSTUFF` is null. I have tried changing this to use jQuery's $.param as below:

```
$http({ method: "POST", url: MYURL_URL, params: $.param(myObject), cache: false });
```

I think the issue here is caused because I cannot successfully pass the `myObject.ARRAYOFSTUFF` around. I have passed arrays before in `$http POSTs` but never with an object like this.

I did change my endpoint to pass only the ARRAY but I have the same problem that when it got to the endpoint it was `null`.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `params` to `data`:

```
$http({ method: "POST", url: MYURL_URL, data: myObject, cache: false });
```

Comment: Oh, how silly of me. Tried that and it works! I will accept the answer shortly (When Stack Overflow will let me!)